# Where is the implementation for tx:advice?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, transactions, aop

I know Spring must implement a "advice" dedicated to transaction, so where is the code that implements the `tx:advice` tag?

I will also appreciate for the `<aop:advisor>` tag's implementation, if you could point out the location in spring jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring uses `BeanDefinitionParser` implementations to parse the XML in XML context files. In this particular case, it uses `org.springframework.transaction.config.TxAdviceBeanDefinitionParser`.